# elasticsearch cluster, master slave setup

Tags: elasticsearch, rackspace

Initially, i was running elasticsearch on a single machine on a rackspace. In the config file, i had 
in the beginning written

```
network.host: localhost
```

Later when i had to run elasticsearch server on two machines , i had to change it to

```
network.host: 123.23.44.23 (basically current ip address of machine)
```

I changed

```
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["123.23.44.23","104.23.44.23"]
```

Now i have two questions:

1.) I have configured one master and one non-master. Since i have changed my network.host. Should i always post to master ip address(when i send the curl request) . Can i still maintain localhost as my posting ip ?

2.)I am also using kibana to visualize the data, since i have changed the network.host. I changed it in the kibana.yml [I had put ip address of master] file as well and restarted it. It stopped working gave me an 502 bad gateway error.
Can anybody give me another to expose my two machines apart from changing network.host property or rectify the above two problems?

I am quite new to elasticsearch cluster, i tried going through other discussion forums but couldn't find relevant information

Thanks!